# How to assign a service keyboard shortcut for a specific application (non global)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, google-chrome

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to an Automator created service.

- This must be working only for the application the service was created for.
- It should override the default application keyboard shortcut (if any).

Example: Using my text editor, if I press F5, I want it to launch a reload Chrome tab service as explained on Stack Overflow [Mac: reloading document in Chrome or Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091235/mac-reloading-document-in-chrome-or-firefox), but without activating the normal function associated to this key in the software.

Comment: Hmm - I believe it's undefined behavior which of the two conflicting key commands activate in the case that an application specific override conflicts with a system wide command.

Answer (score 2):

Going from your example, I assume:

- You have an existing Automator service that reloads a Chrome tab.
- It is set to work in TextEdit only.
- It is installed (in `~/Library/Services`).

To set an application-specific shortcut then:

1. Open **System Preferences > Keyboard**
2. Go to the **Shortcuts** tab and choose **App Shortcuts** at the bottom of the list.
3. Create a new shortcut:

   - Restrict the shortcut to TextEdit
   - The name must be exactly the same as the menu title of the service

[image]